# How to make Video Effects by ffmpeg from command line to Node JS?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am working on ffmpeg. I have already worked on several work for editor. But currently I need to make effect on video. I have got command line command to give effect. But I cant convert it to node Js :

```
cellauto: ffplay -f lavfi -i cellauto=rule=110

life: ffplay -f lavfi -i life=s=300x200:mold=10:r=60:ratio=0.1:death_color=#C83232:life_color=#00ff00,scale=1200:800:flags=16
```

So I need to converrt it in filter by node js.

Comment: What library do you use for working with ffmpeg? Or do you run it as external command using exec?

Comment: I am using fluent-ffmpeg & ffmpeg module in node js